# Creating subscription using graphene relay

Tags: graphql, graphene-python, graphql-subscriptions, graphql-mutation

I am new to graphQL graphene(python). I would like to know if it is possible to create **subscription** root type using graphene. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is definitely possible. You can find examples on how to do that here: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-ws

Here is an example from that repo:

```
import asyncio
import graphene


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    base = graphene.String()


class Subscription(graphene.ObjectType):
    count_seconds = graphene.Float(up_to=graphene.Int())

    async def resolve_count_seconds(root, info, up_to):
        for i in range(up_to):
            yield i
            await asyncio.sleep(1.)
        yield up_to


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, subscription=Subscription)
```

Comment: That gives me the following error during execute: `Subscription must return Async Iterable or Observable. Received: <async_generator object ... at ...>'`